# Spring Boot With Maven Shade Plugin - Controllers not mapped (404 Error)

Tags: spring-boot, maven-shade-plugin, spring-boot-maven-plugin

For my Spring boot application with embedded tomcat, due to some limitation I need to do away with         `spring-boot-maven-plugin` and need to use `maven-shade-plugin`. With maven package command I could successfully create the jar file. However, all my controllers stopped working and gives me 404 error. Also static content placed in my resources folder are not being served anymore. Always getting 404 error.

my pom.xml

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.7</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies> 

<build>
    <plugins>

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>

            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>

                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>abc.MyMainClass</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>


    </plugins>
</build>
```

I run the application as usual:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyMainClass{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyMainClass.class, args);
    }   
}
```

Also I had to create following EmbeddedServletContainerFactory bean, otherwise an error will be thrown.

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory servletContainer() {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();
    return tomcat;
}
```

Finally, I just have a one sample controller,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/car", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public Car test() {
    return new Car();
}
```

This same code works without any issue when I use spring-boot-maven plugin. Soon after I started using maven-shade-plugin, tomcat boots up successfully. however, all controllers gives me 404 error. Please guide me if I'm doing anything wrong.

Comment: It would be helpful if someone can provide a working example of Spring Boot with maven shade plugin. Thanks.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

It is very simple if you want to migrate from spring-boot-maven plugin to maven-shade plugin. I've added following plugin information to pom.xml and problem resolved.

(https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/1.2.6.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-1.2.6.RELEASE.pom)

Dependency management:

```
    <dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <!-- Import dependency management from Spring Boot -->
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Build plugins:

```
<build>


    <plugins>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java.version}</source>
                <target>${java.version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>


        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <dependencies>
                <dependency>
                    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
                </dependency>
            </dependencies>
            <configuration>
                <keepDependenciesWithProvidedScope>true</keepDependenciesWithProvidedScope>
                <createDependencyReducedPom>true</createDependencyReducedPom>
                <filters>
                    <filter>
                        <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                            <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </filter>
                </filters>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <transformers>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.springframework.boot.maven.PropertiesMergingResourceTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.factories</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                            </transformer>
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />
                            <transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>sg.butterfly.emenu.api.config.EmenuApp</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
                        </transformers>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the existing one,try using AppendingTransformer,for example :

```
<transformer
                                implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                <mainClass>abc.MyMainClass</mainClass>
                            </transformer>
<transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                 <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                         <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                 <resource>META-INF/spring.tooling</resource>
                                </transformer>
```

Refer Doc : https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#AppendingTransformer

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.. I tried and this doesn't work. Seems the way I migrate from spring-boot-maven plugin to maven-shade-plugin is wrong. Need to figure out how to configure it properly.

Answer (score 0):

I reference the link about [Cannot find 'manifestEntries' in class org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57564196/cannot-find-manifestentries-in-class-org-apache-maven-plugins-shade-resource-s)

The code is a little different,because it just add an  for execution.I use the same code like before,but it will show some bugs.
In this way,I can package it well.

```html
<execution>
                        <id>shade-my-jar</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.handlers</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.springframework.boot.maven.PropertiesMergingResourceTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.factories</resource>
                                </transformer>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.AppendingTransformer">
                                    <resource>META-INF/spring.schemas</resource>
                                </transformer>
<!--                                <transformer-->
<!--                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ServicesResourceTransformer" />-->
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <manifestEntries>
                                        <Main-Class>demo.OrtoolsApplication</Main-Class>
                                    </manifestEntries>
                                </transformer>

                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
```